# JS How to add display:none to the style of tag<i>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table

I can already get the id of tr (blue box in the picture)

I want to add `display:none` to the style of tag `<i>` through the id (red box in the picture)

This is my idea, I wonder if it can be done?

Or how should I accomplish it?

tr may have 0 or more, so id may also have 0 or more

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual HTML (as text, not a picture). Explain which data you have and describe accurately which element(s) in particular you want to target

Comment: __tr may have 0 or more__ . What they have?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @CodeThing They are like blue and red boxes. The difference is that the id of tr is different and some of the values ​​inside are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the `<tr>` ID and want to target the first `<i>` element within the 2nd `<td>`, you can use a fairly simple query selector

```js
const id = "b24214a8f170cef7.txt";
const el = document.getElementById(id)?.querySelector("td:nth-child(2) > i");
if (el) {
  el.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr id="b24214a8f170cef7.txt">
    <td>(...)</td>
    <td>
      <i>I am the &lt;i&gt; tag</i>
      <a href="#">Some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b24214b8f170cef7.txt">
    <td>(...)</td>
    <td>
      <i>I am the &lt;i&gt; tag</i>
      <a href="#">Some link</a>
    </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```